# Wordpress custom menu list style type

Tags: wordpress

I´m having the problem with wordpress, that i use a custom menu to show me image-links. But i just cant get rid of the list-style-type-circle. I searched all the wordpress code and deleted every single of these circle-expressions, but still it shows up.

Heres the link to the page, on the left side you have the menu.

http://web318.login-11.hoststar.at/ben/az3wp/

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 121 of `style.css` is causing this, it uses:

```
ul {
    list-style: disc;
}
```

Add the following to override it:

```
.menu-item {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Or remove the rule all together.

Answer (score 0):

Change `list-style` to none around line number 121 at `/wp-content/themes/az31/style.css`

```
ul { list-style: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```